# Why does npm become undefined when I check node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmpWw.png)

So I'm learning react and I was checking to see if npm had downloaded properly, and it seems to be running fine, but after I type in node and then check npm again, it says that it is not defined. The only way for me to get npm to work is to kill the terminal and make a new one.

Can someone help me understand this? It is not a huge roadblock or anything but it bothers me, because the tutorial I watched to download node would check to see if node was downlaoded and then npm, and did not have this issue.

Comment: running `node` puts you into a node runtime, `npm` is not a defined variable.

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you, that helps. Is there a reason why that is? If npm is part of node shouldn't it run in the node runtime? thanks

Comment: @nathan.io Not quite (well, you can `require("npm")` to use it as a library, but that's beside the point). It's a separate tool since it separately manages Node packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `node` in terminal **without any keys** you start new session of **NodeJS** application.
It means that every next line you will write would be executed as **javascript code** until you end the session either by pressing `Ctrl+C` twice, typing `.exit` or manualy closing the terminal.
In your case you're trying to execute

```js
npm
```

as a part of the script.
In this case **NodeJS** environment is looking for any *function*, any *variable* or something with the name `npm` to look into but hasn't find anything.
That's why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to save the JS file first before running

> npm test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A good way to check if a program is installed and on the path, is using the version / help arguments.

```
node --version
```

Different programs have different behaviors when not passing arguments, the ones that require arguments will usually print out the help section. Node will enter interactive mode, where node will run the code written in the terminal session.

TLDR:
To check whether a program is installed try

```
<executable> -v
```

If your terminal attached to a different program, most programs will let you exit with Ctrl + C / Cmd + C (Sending SIGTERM signal)